# Why can I not import TensorFlow package in Python Idle?

Tags: python, windows, numpy, tensorflow, package

I installed Tensorflow on Windows, using pip (Python 3.5)

```
C:\> pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Afterwards, I went to my command line and succesfully ran:

```
>> python
>> import tensorflow as tf
```

However, then I opened up Python IDLE (3.5) and tried to import tensorflow, with no luck:

```
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Same story with numpy. My Numpy and tensorflow packages are installed here:

```
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you **sure** you are using the correct IDLE?

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I am sorry... I just checked and my Command prompt was using python 3.5.2 and my IDLE was using 3.5.1. I was fooled by the 3.5... many thanks... sorry. If you post an answer with how to check the python versions, I will accept it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got your answer. As asked here is how you can check your python version.
`import sys
print (sys.version)`

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem in Python version 3.6. Finally, I managed to solve it by accessing Windows Command Prompt in Admin mode and type 
to enter to python IDLE

> > python

and successfully import tensorflow

> > import tensorflow as tf

and checked the version with

> > print(tf.**version**)